# Delete custom fields on post publish?

Tags: custom-field, customization

I have some custom fields, for example one is named "thumb". Custom field is generated automatically by some plugin. I do not use it at all.

Is there any function which will delete that custom field on post publish?

Comment: I would advice you not to just randomly delete meta-data generated by a plugin without knowing what it is for. In any case why is it a problem to have that field anyway? Is it displayed in your theme?

Comment: I do not wish to randomly delete custom fields, just some fields which are not used at all. It is not just one, it is several same custom fields in all posts. That custom fields are not used in my theme, they are optional, and just waste space in database, which will have many posts.

Comment: So is this leftovers from a plugin you *do not use anymore*? Otherwise there will probably be some reason it is there.

Comment: I still use that plugin, and it will create that unused custom fields for all new posts in future. So I need way to delete that custom fields.